# Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions both defined and continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: functions, continuity, proof-writing

Suppose that $\sqrt{7}f(0) - g(0) = 1$ and $\sqrt{7}f(1)-g(1)=e+1$. Prove that $\exists\,\, 0<x<1$ such that $$3\sqrt{7}f(x) - 3\left(g(x)+e^x\right) = \sqrt{7}$$

I honestly haven't a clue where I can even start this question. I have a hunch that it may be asking for some type of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ characterization but I'm really not sure.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use intermediate value theorem to the function $h(x)=3{\sqrt7}f(x)−3(g(x)+e^x)$.
$h(0)=0$ and $h(1)=3$ 
Note that $0<\sqrt7<3$
Since h is continuous, there exists $c\in (0,1) $ such that $h(c)=\sqrt7$.